# MS4W install issue

Tags: mapserver, ms4w

Windows 11
MS4W 4.0.5

When I installed from the standard download, I chose port 8091. After the install, two services appear:

- ApacheMS4WWebServer:port81
- ApacheMS4WWebServer:port8091

Why are there two services?

The second one starts but the first one won't start (see later).

Webaccess to the port 8091 service works with things like this:

http://localhost:8091/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/apps/australia/australia.map&MODE=browse&TEMPLATE=openlayers&LAYERS=all

And I can pan and zoom around.

However, when I connect qGIS using
http://localhost:8091/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/apps/australia/australia.map

I can see the layers in the service but when I add a layer to the QGIS map I get this in the WMS log message pane:

2023-12-04T17:37:15     WARNING    Map request failed [error: Connection refused url: http://localhost:81/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=c:/ws4w/apps/australia/australia.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-54.75390000000000157,112.9069999999999965,-25.52202088068180785,159.1020000000000039&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=868&HEIGHT=549&LAYERS=States&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=240&MAP_RESOLUTION=240&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:240&TRANSPARENT=TRUE]

Why is it redirecting to port 81?

Why does the port 81 service not start?
Here are the 4 messages written to the Windows event log:

The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> > > (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8091     .

The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> > > (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8091     .

The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> > > AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down

The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> > > AH00015: Unable to open logs     .

If this helps, the Apache error_log has the following error:

[Tue Dec 05 11:24:08.957715 2023] [cgi:error] [pid 16028:tid 1120] [client ::1:61592] AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: C:/ms4w/Apache/cgi-bin/img, referer: http://localhost:8091/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:/ms4w/apps/australia/australia.map&MODE=browse&TEMPLATE=openlayers&LAYERS=all

Comment: Is this the file that you used for installation https://ms4w.com/release/ms4w-4.0.5-setup.exe? What do you have as "wms_onlineresource" https://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html in your mapfile?